# How to get html page source in selenium matching requests page source

Tags: python, selenium

How do I get the html source of a page with selenium that matches the python requests page source, i.e. in the code below how do I get content from selenium to match r from requests ?

Selenium

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="/usr/local/bin/chromedriver", chrome_options=options)
with contextlib.closing(driver) as browser:
    browser.get(link)
    content=browser.page_source
```

Python requests

```
r = request.urlopen(link).read().decode('utf-8')
```

Comment: If the page has dynamic javascript, then the sources won't match, because Selenium executes the javascript but requests doesn't.

Comment: @JohnGordon The above comment ^^^ would have been a great answer for the future readers.